# How to make gvim always confirm quit when pressing the X button on the window

Tags: gvim

Using `set confirm` or the confirm-quit plugin makes it so that vim always confirms quit. But in **gvim**, if you just press the X at the top, it always quits -- no confirmation (unless the file is unsaved)

Sometimes I open 3+ tabs with several buffers in each -- if I reflexively hit that X when everything is saved, then "Boom", the whole workspace is gone. I'd really like a confirmation box.

[image]

Comment: When I wrote confirm_quit.vim a few years ago the only way I could figure out how to do this was by intercepting the `:q`, `ZZ`, etc. commands to ask for confirmation first; that's why it doesn't work with the "X". I'm not sure if there's any other way; I can't think of one now either, but perhaps I missed something.